# Route on tabs to children

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having some difficulty for set up my routes.
In my app-rougin.module.ts I instantiated listRoutes with params.

```
const listRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MlsComponent,
    },
  {
    path: 'vente',
    component: VenteComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'location',
    component: LocationComponent,  
  },
  {
    path: 'venteLocation',
    component: VenteLocationComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(listRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

In my template :

```
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let route of listRoutes" routerLink= {{route.path}} ><a *ngFor="let route of listRoutes"></a></mat-tab>
```

I think my child component isn't receiving the data.
How can I send the information listRoutes to the child component?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using routes as a variable you can get it with defining 'routerLink' with square brackets.

**[routerLink]= "route.path"**